# Position elements according to screen size in Objective C, ios6, Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which scrolls horizontally from left to right.

I want to be able to vertically position my UIScrollView on the Y axis according to the screen size of the iPhone. E.g iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.

```
CGFloat startX = (70.0f * ((float)[_attachments count] - 1.0f) + padding);
CGFloat startY = 295;
CGFloat width = 64;
CGFloat height = 64;
```

Right now I start my Y position at 295 which works okay with the iPhone 4 but not on iPhone 5.

How would I change the startY to accommodate the same position for different screen size?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
{
     //iphone5
}
else
{
     //iphone4
}
```

You can set your y value accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do use `layoutSubviews` in your view ...

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  CGRect frame = self.bounds;
  frame.origin.y += frame.size.height - _scrollView.frame.size.height;
  if ( ! CGRectEqualToRect( _scrollView.frame, frame ) {
    _scrollView.frame = frame;
  }
}
```

... I assume that your horizontal scroll view is in `_scrollView` ivar and also that the `_scrollView.frame.size.height` contains correct height of your `_scrollView`. If not, replace `_scrollView.frame.size.height` with some constant which does contain your `UIScrollView` height.

Why the condition with `CGRectEqualToRect`? Because `layoutSubviews` can be called very often and when you set new frame (even if it equals) to it, `UIScrollView` can stop scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this-

first get the width and the height of the screen

```
CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds ;
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds)  ;
```

now create a method which will do some calculations and return an int

```
-(NSInteger) getwidth:-(NSInteger *) value
{
int temp = (value * 100) / 480;
return int((height * temp) / 100);
}

-(NSInteger) getheight:-(NSInteger *) value
{
 var temp = (value * 100) / 320;
return int((width * temp) / 100);
}
```

now set the bounds of view according to these function

```
actind.frame=CGRectMake(getWidth(20),getheight(20),16,16);
```

this will work on all the devices and the views will arrange themselves according to the width and height of the screen.

hope this will help for you. :)